# Linq split collection into two based on having children (parentId)

Tags: c#, linq

Assuming model (Used for both questions and answers to questions)

```
Question
int QuestionId
string Text
int? ParentId
int? UserId

List<Question> allQuestions = db.Fetch<Question>(@"Select * FROM Question");
```

How can split the question collection above into two collections based on ParentId and UserId. Where the first collection contains Questions with answers by an certain UserId, and the second collection contains questions without answers by that UserId?

List`<Question>` questionsAndAnswers_NotAnsweredByUserId5 = allQuestions.(Linq?)

List`<Question>` questionsAndAnswers_AnsweredByUserId5 = allQuestions.(Linq?)

Answer (score 0):

```
var byThatUser = allQuestions.Where(q => q.ParentId == certainUserId).ToList();

var notByThatUser = allQuestions.Where(q => q.ParentId != certainUserId).ToList();
```